# 'QVTKWidget.h' file not found

Tags: c++, cmake, vtk, qvtkwidget

I installed PCL 1.8.0 on Ubuntu 18.04 but I encountered an error while installing a repo.

```
[ 88%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/tviewer.dir/tviewer/tviewer_widget/tviewer_widget.cpp.o
In file included from /home/gpu-1/Téléchargements/ForestMetrics/build/third-party/tviewer/tviewer-prefix/src/tviewer/tviewer/tviewer_widget/tviewer_widget.cpp:6:0:
/home/gpu-1/Téléchargements/ForestMetrics/build/third-party/tviewer/tviewer-prefix/src/tviewer/tviewer/tviewer_widget/tviewer_widget.h:12:10: fatal error: QVTKWidget.h: Aucun fichier ou dossier de ce type
 #include <QVTKWidget.h>
          ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~
compilation terminated.
CMakeFiles/tviewer.dir/build.make:354: recipe for target 'CMakeFiles/tviewer.dir/tviewer/tviewer_widget/tviewer_widget.cpp.o' failed
make[5]: *** [CMakeFiles/tviewer.dir/tviewer/tviewer_widget/tviewer_widget.cpp.o] Error 1
CMakeFiles/Makefile2:67: recipe for target 'CMakeFiles/tviewer.dir/all' failed
make[4]: *** [CMakeFiles/tviewer.dir/all] Error 2
Makefile:129: recipe for target 'all' failed
make[3]: *** [all] Error 2
third-party/tviewer/CMakeFiles/tviewer.dir/build.make:110: recipe for target 'third-party/tviewer/tviewer-prefix/src/tviewer-stamp/tviewer-build' failed
make[2]: *** [third-party/tviewer/tviewer-prefix/src/tviewer-stamp/tviewer-build] Error 2
CMakeFiles/Makefile2:385: recipe for target 'third-party/tviewer/CMakeFiles/tviewer.dir/all' failed
make[1]: *** [third-party/tviewer/CMakeFiles/tviewer.dir/all] Error 2
Makefile:83: recipe for target 'all' failed
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

However I installed `sudo apt-get install libvtk6-qt-dev` without any error.

Any idea ? Many Thanks !

Comment: Just installing the library isn't enough. You need to tell your compiler / build system where to find its headers. Did you?

Comment: I am quite new I don't think I did, how should I do ? Thanks

Comment: @underscore_d: The libraries installed via system package manager should be detected by the CMake project without any hints from the user. And if the project don't find some library, it should report that at **configuration** stage, not when *compiling*. Probably, PCL detects the library in a wrong way.

Comment: The fact is that in usr/include/vtk6.3 I do not have this file, whereas I installed vtk. Actually I do not have any QVTK-files.